# Angle between axes in an n-dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been wondering about this question, which I heard from someone else who did not know the answer, for a while.
What is the angle between the coordinate axes for an arbitrary n-dimensional system?
Wouldn't the angle still be 90 degrees between all the axes? After all, in 2D Cartesian, the angle is 90 degrees, and in 3D all the angles are still 90, you've just added a new dimension. In 4D, 5D....nD, would it still just be 90?

Comment: It depends on how you measure angles. Rather than dealing with explicit angles which are more of a planar (two dimensional) thing, one typically uses the inner (or dot) product as a measure of alignment (or not).

Comment: Although if you're measuring angles between two axes in $n$-dimensional space, these two axes live in a $2$-dimensional plane, and are subject to all of the usual $2$-dimensional ways of measuring things...

Comment: One usually chooses an orthonormal basis in a Euclidean space, which in particular makes distinct basis vectors (and the axes defined by them) at right angles. It is not impossible to use other bases though, which might determine non-orthogonal axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Euclidean space ($\mathbb{R^n}$), the angle $\theta$ between two vectors $u,v$ can be related to the dot product and lengths by the formula
$$
u \cdot v = \cos (\theta) |u| |v|
$$
So if $u$ and $v$ are vectors along the coordinate axes, something like
$$
u = (0,\ldots, 1, \ldots, 0) \qquad v = (0,\ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)
$$
where the 1 is in different places, then $u \cdot v = 0$. Then $\cos(\theta) |u||v| = 0$. Since $|u| = |v| = 1$, it must be that $\cos \theta = 0$. The solutions to that for $\theta$ are $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}, \ldots$. In terms of degrees, these angles are $90^\circ, 270^\circ, \ldots 90^\circ + n180^\circ$ for any integer $n$. Because we usually think of angles as restricted to the interval $(0,180^\circ)$, this means $\theta = 90^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

For standard coordinate system, yes. A scalar product (1,0...,0.... 0).(0,1,...0...0) is always 0.